# Join CSV data to a raster file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, combine, habitat-modeling

I am trying to join three data files to a raster grid:

[image: Example of data]

I have environmental data in the centre of each grid cell (delimited text layer), Sightings (delimited text layer), effort points (delimited text layer), and track lines (points2one). The grid is a raster layer.
How can I join the data which is within each grid cell to form a single data set to export?

Comment: Values you want in raster are attributes of grid layer? In that case i would calculate centoids of your grid (vector>geometry tools>polygon centroids) then use rasterize tool (raster>conversion>rasterize)

Comment: Depending on your data and need you can combine them already by merging centroid layers or later merging rasters (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/150327/16109).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to add the information from your raster layer(s) to the point shapefiles in order to use the environmental data for modelling the probability of your animal(?) sightings in the given landscape. So what you want is to extract the information from the raster and add it to each given location (x,y coordinate of point shapefile).

Interestingly, there is no easy way doing this in standalone QGIS. But as **you can use the SAGA toolbox in the processing environment**, you can use the "**add raster values to points**" tool from the SAGA vector point tools menu.