Create raster in which each cell value is the maxium among the cell values of a series of overlapping rasters
I have a series of 144 rasters with the same extent but different pixel values, which I require to be combined into a single raster. My objective is to create a new raster where each pixel value is the maximum value of the 144 overlapping pixels.

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused question/Best answer model operates. Each and every Question always needs a complete problem statement. The most common comments here are "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?" Without these details, the Question is likely to be closed until they are added. Please [Edit] the Question to specify the GIS software in use, what you have tried, and describe the problem encountered.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150312/combining-multiple-overlapping-rasters-retain-maximum-value?noredirect=1&lq=1
